# Can I get a row from a table without looping trough the whole table?

Tags: table

I wanted to use a table to add global glosery, for translation purposes. (The page is in Norwegian, but need to be understandable for the whole team.) Also it should be accessable for copywriter to change the text. I was first making a matrix for this, to be able to access each word that are being translated. But then I was thinking it would be easier to use a table, since you then can have a default translation, that the copy writer later could change.

Is there anyway to access a table row?

[image]

Comment: How is your table setup, can you provide a screenshot? Also post any code you've attempted if possible. If I understand what you're trying to do, then this plugin might be of use to you: https://plugins.craftcms.com/translations-admin

Comment: I think this is roughly a duplicate of this question: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28449/query-craft-cms-table-field-for-exact-values and the consensus answer is "it's probably possible, but not out of the box"

Comment: I've added the table in the question

Comment: Yes this seems like a tricky thing to do with a table. Depending on how many translations there are you could consider creating a field per phrase, this would be the best way performance-wise. Does your site have a different locale setup for each language?